# Which method will reduce the LOG in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, ssis

I have one History Table(Parent Table) which having 10 million rows. i need to move the 6 month older data to another database(BackUp Table) and delete those data from the parent History table. which method i should have to use?

Method 1
1. Insert all data from Parent table to BackUp Table
2. Truncate the parent table
3. Insert the data from Backup table to parent table which are not less than 6 months

Method 2

1. Using SSIS to take the data from the Parent table to BackUp tables
2. After that delete from the parent table.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to read this [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). I'd suspect that if you don't, you may stop receiving help here. SO is designed to work by asking questions, accepting correct (or most helpful) answers, and upvoting those answers that help you solve your problem. Thanks. :)

Comment: does the table contains static data? or does the row count increase every second?

Comment: Parent table is populating using a trigger. Not a static table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you use the partitions? If the data is partitioned according to the month, you could simply wipe off the entire partition? This is just a thought. I dont know the implications of partitioning on logging!

Comment: Thank you for the replay. I need study partition first. 
One question is that:
The parent table which I have mentioned is not used for any querying. So idea is to remove all the data from that database table to another database in another disk. Will that purpose satisfies if I go for partitioning? I am completely unaware of partitioning. I will check it and updates you.
Thank you